# Codeigniter creating new session on every page load

Tags: php, codeigniter

I used codeigniter 2.1.0 to develop and e-commerce site for a client.
The site has been working well for about 3 months then all of a sudden, logins were not sticking, session data was not being set.
I checked the database and noticed a new session was being created on every page load.

Here are my config value

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'myu';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = '_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 3600;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

I edited the user_agent field on session table to accommodate long user_agent strings.
What could be the problem? i'll be greatful for any help

Comment: see http://amerkhalid.com/codeigniter-creating-a-new-session-with-each-page-load/

Comment: please let us know if that link @goldenparrot posted helped you out

Comment: @Tom - If you want to write an answer based on the content linked above, please do so. However, make the answer stand on its own and not require us to have to visit the site to see the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have correct domain set in `/application/config/config.php` at `$config['cookie_domain']`

Answer (score 1):

You should also check the size of "user_agent" in your session table. I got some problems with "varchar(40)" as the user-agent of Firefox in MacOS (mountain lion, version 20.0) reports more than 60 characters in your UA.

Changing the field from "varchar(40)" to "varchar(255)" solved my issue.

Comment: This was my problem as well - it puzzles me why the default `ci_session` table has this quite dumb setup.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this in the hope that it helps other people.  I have tried many of the suggestions mentioned at multiple sites and worked on this for 2 days.  None of the solutions worked.

I then decided to check what was showing in my cookie.  I set `$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']   = FALSE;` in the config.php file so that I can read the data and deleted all my old cookies.  I also changed the `$config['sess_cookie_name']` to the website name.  It was originally the default 'cisession'.  All of a sudden, it started working properly.  I don't know if it was the clearing out of my old cookies or turning off the encryption or changing the name that made the difference, but I'm glad that it's finally working.  I'm guessing that maybe my cookie was corrupted.  Since I have seen sites suggesting completely different advice for the same settings (e.g., some say leave ['cookie_domain'] blank, some say add in your root domain (with at least 2 periods), etc.), I am including my settings in config.php file:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'easyeverydayenglish';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 14400;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = ".eee.loc";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

Now onto my next problem of trying to get CI to work on goDaddy.  Arghh.