# Page refresh cause a session cookie to be created in Codeigniter and a record inserted in the session table

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-cookies, page-refresh

Reading through so many things but haven't found a solution to my problem. I use ajax requests to authenticate my users on the website. The login and logout ajax requests work absolutely fine. The login call creates the session cookie and stores data in the session table. The logout call clears the cookie and removes the data from the database. All this works as expected.

I'm testing this on my localhost with WAMP server.

The most irritating thing is if all cookies are cleared and the session table is completely empty, when I refresh my webpage a session cookie gets generated from somewhere. Along with that I also get a record inserted into the session table with the same session id as in the browser cookie. There is no user data present in that database record so I'm really confused and frustrated as to from where is this cookie getting created. I'm autoloading my session library. As of now I don't want to go back to native sessions so please suggest.

session configuration is as below. Can sess_update() help here somehow.

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Comment: Upon loading of the session library, CodeIgniter creates a session if it does not exist. ([Source](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Session.php#L104))  Is this an issue for you or you were just curious?

Comment: Okay I get that and the session is established and a session cookie is created in the user's browser. This very session cookie must be updated in case the user logs in to my website with a renewed session id. What i don't understand is why is it creating two records in the session table (two sessions from same IP and useragent). I want the session table to only have one record for each user which gets destroyed on session destroy function. If it has multiple records then I cannot authenticate users based on a single session id. Please clear me up a bit, I'm lost.

Comment: I encourage you to read the [documentation of the class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html).  It actually states that it creates a session on load. Furthermore, it also explain how to use the class. You do not have to authenticate user based on the session ID, the library does it for you.  Simply use `$this->session->userdata('item');` to get data and `$this->session->set_userdata($array);` to set data.

Comment: Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446297/codeigniter-creating-new-session-on-every-page-load) also has good hints as to why a new session id would be created every-time.